# get users with special roles in wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I am developing a plugin for wordpress and I want to get list of users with role1 or role2 or role3 or role4. I use the code below to get users with role1 but I don't know how should I change it to get users of more than 1 role.

```
$jobholders = get_users( 'orderby=nicename&role=jobholder' );
```

Answer (score 2):

I thought that using a [MySQL wildcard](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html) would work because the query in the class [`WP_User_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query) is built with LIKE, but it doesn't: `get_users(array('role' => 'job%'))`.

The solution has to be with the action hook `pre_user_query`:

```
/**
 * Filter the mysql query for get_users when searching for the role "job" to search for "%job%"
 */
add_action( 'pre_user_query', 'so_25594548' );

function so_25594548( $user_search ) 
{
    $search_str = '%\"job\"%';

    # Quotes around $search_str so we don't need to escape the backslashes
    if( false === strpos( $user_search->query_where, "$search_str" ) )
        return;

    # Simplify the LIKE to do a loose search
    $user_search->query_where = str_replace( 
        "$search_str", 
        '%job%', 
        $user_search->query_where 
    );
}
```

It considers that we have two roles, `jobseeker` and `jobholder`, and to search for both we would use this call, with an inexistant role but with a string that both contain (no wildcards): **`get_users(array('role' => 'job');`**. This makes `query_where` to be like this:

```sql
WHERE 1=1 AND ( (wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'wp_capabilities' AND CAST(wp_usermeta.meta_value AS CHAR) LIKE '%\"job\"%') )
```

`wp_capabilities` is a serialized array, so it looks for a perfect match for `job` between wildcards.